# Angular how to get specific element in json result from C# API

Tags: angular

I am able to get json response from c# api, but when I try to display specific element in it, it shows undefined.

1.My angular service:

```
PostFileImport(uploadBy:string, periodId: number ,fileToUpload: File): Observable<any> {
          const endpoint = constants.BaseUrl_UAT + 'api/Vote/' + 'VotingRoster'
          //?periodId='+periodId +'&uploadBy='+uploadBy
          let formData = new FormData();
          formData.append('fileKey', fileToUpload, fileToUpload.name);
    
      let params = new HttpParams().set("periodId",periodId.toString()).set("uploadBy",uploadBy)

      const options = {
        params: params,
        reportProgress: true,
        responseType: 'arraybuffer' as 'json'
      };

    const req = new HttpRequest('POST', endpoint, formData, options);
    return this.http.request(req);
    //return this.http.post(endpoint, formData, options);
  }
```

2. ts file excerpt that calls the API

   ```
   this.UploadService.PostFileImport('sss', this.PeriodId, this.uploadFile)
           .subscribe((res:any) => {
            this.Sectortest = res.Sector;
            this.data = res;
            console.log("Sector:")
            console.log(this.Sectortest)
            console.log("all")
            console.log(this.data)
              },
              error => {
                 console.error(error)
              }
           )
          console.log("fisnihed calling API..")
           }
   ```
3. My API Controller that returns the Json result

   ```
        [HttpPost]
        public async Task<IHttpActionResult> VotingRoster(string uploadBy, int periodId)
        {
            //ActionResponse aRes = new ActionResponse();
            try
            {
                var dal = new IIVoteCombinationsDAL();

                    var file = HttpContext.Current.Request.Files.Get(0);
                    if (file == null)
                    {
                        throw new InvalidOperationException("Upload file is required");
                    }

                    var result = new RosterLoad();
                    result = dal.UploadRosterValidationFileAsync(
                        new IIVoteCombinationsDAL.UploadRosterValidationFileParams
                        {
                            FileStream = file.InputStream,
                            UploadBy = uploadBy,
                            PeriodId = periodId
                        }
                    );

                return Ok(result);

                //return Task.FromResult<IHttpActionResult>(Ok(result));

            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                return InternalServerError(ex);
            };


        }
   ```
4. Response when I trigger the API from angular

   ```
   {
    "SOEID": [
        {
            "InvalidSOEID": "7060"
        }
    ],
    "Sector": [
        {
            "Sector": "Banks",
            "Status": "Existing"
        },
        {
            "Sector": "Transportation",
            "Status": "Existing"
        }
    ],
    "Industry": [
        {
            "Industry": "ccc",
            "Status": "New"
        }
    ]
   }
   ```
5. Console log shows undefined when I try to get the element Sector

[image]

Comment: Have you tried `console.log(req);` just to be sure it contains what you expect?

Comment: @mazooma yes tried that. it returns some information but there is no actual data from the result that i was looking for